# how to insert a button in select to add new item in select item list?

Tags: 7

I am using a select(combobox) to insert category of device as input. And in that combobox I wish to add a button at end of item list of categories to add new category. When user clicks that button there must be a text box appeared at end of list or modal like Ctools to add new category. Please help me to get this done thank you.

Comment: Selects cannot contain buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for the something similar to the [select_or_other](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module. I believe your request is a "modern" implementation of this module, I've seen it on some sites. You might try to do some CSS/JS wizardry to make the Select or Other module fit your need.